# keeping the ressource id returned by ssh2_connect() php

Tags: php, ssh

When i try to keep the ressource id which is returned by ssh2_connect() in session or get , the content of the variable dissapear. i tried to load it with javascript but it doesn't work. My question is how to solve this problem here is my code :

```
<?php
    session_start();
         if (!function_exists("ssh2_connect")) die("function ssh2_connect doesn't exist");
    // log in at server1.example.com on port 22
    echo $_SESSION['address'];
    if(!($con = ssh2_connect($_SESSION['address'], 22))){
        echo "fail: unable to establish connection\n";
    } else { 
        // try to authenticate with username root, password secretpassword
        if(!ssh2_auth_password($con, $_SESSION['login'], $_SESSION['password'])) {
            echo "fail: unable to authenticate\n";
        } else {
            // allright, we're in!
            echo "okay: logged in...<br>";

            $shell = ssh2_shell($con);

    }
    }
    ?>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function display()
    {
     var v = '<?php echo $shell; ?>';
    $('#intro').load('content/test.php?con='+v);
    }
    </script>


    </head>
```

Comment: Resources are all freed when a script exits.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this. When a script exits, all its network connections and file streams are closed. Resources can't be passed from one script invocation to another, so it doesn't make sense to save them in sessions, cookies,

Comment: i'am using ssh2 to connect a cisco router , if i want to keep the acces mode (privileged mode or config mode ) how to do it ?

Comment: You have to keep the script running somehow.